# Unit testing LiveData emissions in combination with RxJava

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvvm, rx-java, viewmodel

I have been facing an issue unit testing our business logic. The problem is when I wanted to unit test all the emissions of the livedata. Right now I only get the last emitted value but I wanted to unit test all the values that get emitted one by one.

Here is my rough setup.

Here is how my viewModel `onSaveEvent` click event looks like

```
        disposable.add(finalSource
        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
            .doOnSubscribe {
                // show spinner
                _myLiveData.value = Loading(toShow = true, loadingMessage = "Loading")
            }
            .doAfterTerminate {
                // remove spinner
                _myLiveData.value = Loading(toShow = false)

            }
            .subscribe { resource ->
                // Update either on success or error.
                _myLiveData.value = resource
        }
    )
```

My view model test looks something like this.

```
@Test
fun testOnSaveEvent() {
    // Other setup code.
    Mockito.`when`(myRepo.onSave()).thenReturn(mockSingle)
    myViewModel.onSaveEvent(salesTaxCompanyInfo)

    testScheduleProvider.ui().triggerActions()

    // I see that the value is of type Loading
    val firstValue = myViewModel.myLiveData.getOrAwaitValue()

    // The next value is also Loading, although I would like to see the success event.
    val secondValue = myViewModel.myLiveData.getOrAwaitValue()
}
```

Ideally, I am looking for something on the lines `TestCoroutineDispatcher` listed here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/testing-two-consecutive-livedata-emissions-in-coroutines-5680b693cbf8

While I understand that LiveData only holds the last value it receives I wanted to know if there is any we can unit test the emissions one by one.